# NSTableView not updating on initial loading

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have an NSView with a NSTableView called `personTableView`. In the ViewController class, I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    personTableView.delegate = self
    personTableView.dataSource = self
    personTableView.reloadData()

}
```

and have extended the class to with `NSTableViewDelegate` and `NSTableViewDataSource`

However, when the view appears, the table shows the following (there are only 2 entries that the table should display):

[image]

On my window, I have a button which invokes the following action:

```
@IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let result = CoreDataHandler.fetchCount()
    print("Row Count:\(result)")
    personTableView.reloadData()
    codeTableView.reloadData()
}
```

which when pressed, populates my TableView. I don't understand why it won't load automatically?

I have also tried putting the `personTableView.reloadData()` into `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` to no avail.

## Update:

This is the fetchCount():

```
static func fetchCount() -> Int {
    let context = getContext()
    do {
        let count = try context.count(for: Person.fetchRequest())
        NSLog("Count from fetchCount: %d", count)
        return count
    } catch {
        return 0
    }
}
```

For information, this is the Table Delegate and DataSource functions:

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.personTableView {
            let result = CoreDataHandler.fetchCount()
            //NSLog("Rows in Ext: %@",result)
            return result
        }
        if tableView == self.codeTableView {
            let row = personTableView.selectedRow
            if row > -1 {
                let person = CoreDataHandler.fetchPerson()?[row]
                print("Person= \(String(describing: person?.first))")
                //let result = CoreDataHandler.fetchCodes(person: person!)
                let result = person?.codes
                //print("Person from result: \(String(describing: result?.first.whosAccount?.ibAccount))")
                let count = result!.count
                print("Rows in Codes from viewController dataSource: \(count)")
                return count
            } else {
            return 0
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

        if tableView == self.personTableView {
            guard let person = CoreDataHandler.fetchPerson()?[row] else {
                return nil
            }

            if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
                if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0]  {
                    cell.textField?.stringValue = (person.first ?? nil) ?? ""
                } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[1] {
                    cell.textField?.stringValue = (person.last ?? nil) ?? ""
                } else {
                    cell.textField?.stringValue = (person.ibAccount ?? nil) ?? ""
                }

                return cell

            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        if tableView == self.codeTableView {

            let personRow = personTableView.selectedRow
            if personRow > -1 {
                let person = CoreDataHandler.fetchPerson()?[personRow]
                guard let code = CoreDataHandler.fetchCodes(person: person!)?[row] else {
                    return nil
                }

                if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
                    if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0]  {
                        cell.textField?.stringValue = (String(code.number) )
                        //cell.textField?.stringValue = person?.codes?.allObjects[row] as! String
                    } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[1] {
                        cell.textField?.stringValue = code.code!

                    } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[2] {
                        cell.textField?.stringValue = (code.whosAccount?.ibAccount ?? "")
                    }

                    return cell

                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }

        return nil

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you share what `CoreDataHandler.fetchCount()` does?

Comment: Don't *fetch* anything  in `numberOfRows` and in `objectValueFor`. Don't do that. It's unnecessarily expensive and inefficient. Fetch the stuff once and reload the table view or use `NSFetchResultsController` and Cocoa Bindings. The latter reduces your code by 2/3.

Comment: @vadian: Thanks for the suggestion. I am fairly new to this. If I fetch that data once and have nothing in `numberof Rows` and `objectValueFor`, how do the tables get updated?

Comment: Fetch the data into a data source array `var people = [Person]()`. Return `people.count` in `numberOfRows` and `people[row]` in `objectValueFor`. And replace `(person.first ?? nil) ?? ""` with `person.first ?? ""`. The second nil-coalescing operator is redundant.

Comment: @vadian: Okay but how do I return the `array[row]` in `objectValueFor` as I thought I had to return each column separately

Comment: No, you don't have to if you use Cocoa Bindings. In interface Builder bind the value of the text fields to the table cell view > objectValue.first and the other properties accordingly.

Comment: @vadian: okay. I see how to do it without Cocoa Bindings. Then I just have to update `people` whenever my data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` of `NSTableViewDataSource` and `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` of `NSTableViewDelegate`. Replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
```

by

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

or return strings from `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)`

Comment: That works. Thank you. I don't understand why one works and the others doesn't. Is there a quick explanation?

Comment: See [tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdatasource/1533674-tableview) and [tableView(_:viewFor:row:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1527449-tableview). `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` returns a value object (string, number, image) and `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` returns a view. `NSTableView` can't turn a view into a string.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the table view is being populated based on data stored in the `result` variable. Try making the call to `let result = CoreDataHandler.fetchCount()` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not solve the problem.